# Cakephp use belongsTo on multiple databases

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I need to move a table to another database.

If I do that, all HABTM relations works fine by using tutorials like [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cake-php/tULPQ2zIYi8/MucEVR1kOQ4J).

However there are belongsTo and hasMany relations in other models, which seems are skipped during find() function.

I have found that:

> [if  databases for model is different the join build is bypassed. in source_dbo](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Tutorial-How-make-associations-between-models-on-different-database-td1306742.html#none)

**Is there any smooth workaround without going deep into the code?**

Tables: A, B on DB1
Table: C on DB2

Table: A belongsTo C
Table: B HABTM C

Creating find() on model A, returns only data from table A.
On model B find() returns all joined data from tables B and C.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is disabled/restricted by default (will hopefully find out as I keep developing this product), but after struggling with this for hours, I decided to mess around with the /lib/cake/Model/DataSource/DboSoure.php Class and removed the restriction.

```
//<-- commented out line 1064
//if ($model->useDbConfig === $linkModel->useDbConfig) { 

    if ($bypass) {
            $assocData['fields'] = false;
    }
    if ($this->generateAssociationQuery($model, $linkModel, $type, $assoc, $assocData, $queryData, $external, $null) === true) {
            $linkedModels[$type . '/' . $assoc] = true;
    }

//} <-- commented out line 1071
```

After that everything worked fine for the $belongsTo relationship.

Comment: One unexpected side effect I just noticed is that in the returning the fields for a find('all'), cake will default to using the primary Model  you are querying with for the alias instead of intelligently determining the alias based on the field names.

e.g. You query with model **Comment** in DB1, $belongsTo model **User** in DB2. If you specify the fields as `array('first_name', 'title')` cake returns 

**`array('Comment.first_name', 'Comment.title')`** instead of 
**`array('User.first_name', 'Comment.title')`**

I can live with specifying the model names explicitly for now.